# Is there an offline version of the .net core tooling preview 2?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

Is there an offline version of the .net core tooling preview 2 for Visual Studio 2015 update 3 available? I have a system that isn't connected to the internet and I need to install the tooling preview but cant find any offline installer.

Comment: You can download it as a zipful of binaries here: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download#preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a machine that connects to Internet, run the installer at command line with `/layout` switch (like [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt706497.aspx)) and then you can generate an offline installation folder yourself.